# how to make my checkbox unchecked

Tags: android, checkbox

I've got big problem with checkbox. I've got chceckbox in my MainAdapter(not Activity), I'm checking it and go to the next actvity by clicking on button. Then I return from DefaultActivity to MainActivity and I want checkbox to be unchecked. I also add that checkbox's logic is in Adapter in ViewHolder like this :

```
class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tvC;
    ImageView ivT;
    CheckBox chb;
}
```

and all logic is in getView method.If you don't understand something and you want me to help. Just ask what you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

When you start your new `Activity`, do it calling `startActivityForResult()`. This will call a callback method once you close your second activity, so this way you make sure you'll enter that method once you `finish()` your newly opened `Activity`.

Once in there, simply find your view by id, and uncheck it. This is a sample code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityThatContainsListViewDefinition.class, YourNewActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Afterwards, just override the `onActivityResult()` method.

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox_id);
      cb.setChecked(false);

      break;
  }
}
```

**---- EDIT ----**

All this code would be outside your `Adapter` implementation - so, if you look at the code I provided, in the `Intent`, the first parameter is the context of the `Activity` that **opens** the second one. That means that those two overrides, you have to implement them in the `Activity` that calls the other (in your case, the `MainActivity`).

In your second `Activity` (DefaultActivity), you need to do nothing, just notify the first `Activity` (MainActivity) that it has to unckeck the `CheckBox`. To do so, you simply do something like this when you want to close `DefaultActivity`:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

This way, you're notifying `MainActivity` that it should fire `onActivityResult()` and there's where you uncheck that `CheckBox`.

Comment: Check me but i have to understand it clearly (StarActivity-MainAcitiy, NextActivity-DefaultActivity). I have call startActivityForResult in MainActivity and in DefaultActivity i have to make an Intent with that code and in DefaultActivity i have to override onActivityResult()? Is that correct way of thinking?

Comment: See my update, I provided a bit more of explaination.

Comment: So in MainActivity this :protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox_id);
      cb.setChecked(false);

      break;
  }
}
In DefaultActivity Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();


But if I have class which implement Adapter where should i pase it in this class? Before constructor?

Comment: You have an `Adapter` and you want to start it within it. You must do this probably within your `getView()` method, where you process your `viewHolder`. Simply implement some `onClickListener` on your `convertView` (the second parameter of your `getView()`) and call there the `startActivityOnResult()`.

Comment: I've got two errors first : The constructor Intent(Class<MainActivity>, Class<Zatwierdz>) is undefined;
maybe I should use Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),DefaultActivity.class); ? and second one is:The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){} should I implement it ?

Comment: Sorry, the first is indeed a `Context`. Either use `MainActivity.this` if you can of if not, just `getContext()`. For the second question, you've to use the context too, as you're in an static context. Use this: `context.startActivityForResult(...);`

Comment: final Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DefaultActivity.class);context.startActivityForResult(...); and if it's right ive got error like: The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: Sure, because you have to put the parameters in the call (I didn't include them because I assumed you already was). Basically you have to call: `context.startActivityForResult(i, 1);`

Comment: here is my MainActivity http://pastebin.com/DUz6GWbw 
Adapter http://pastebin.com/jHWqBaf0
DefaultActivity http://pastebin.com/1VgEAZhZ

If you want to take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

To uncheck your checkbox do:

```
chb.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: This doesn't help checkbox is in MyAdapter in ViewHoler class. Where chb.setChecked(false); should be executed ?

Comment: @ in comments for next answer i pasted my code if you want to take look on situation what has place.

Answer (score 0):

if is in adapter you can retrieve it in when getView() is called...

e.g.

holder.chb.setChecked(false);

with this the checkbox will be unchecked every time that de adapter is notified or created again

Comment: I want checkbox to be unchecked after returning from next activity. The chceck box should be unchecked somehow when the return button was pressed. Down in comments is my code if you want to take look on it to understand.